# pythonでの正規表現について教えてください

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

いろいろと調べてみましたが、なかなか理解に苦しんでおります。

下記のような条件の場合の正規表現を教えてください。

対象ファイル名について
1.n番目からm番目の文字列を抜き出す
2.n番目からm番目の文字列を削除する
3.最初からn番目までを抜き出す
4.最後からn番目までを抜き出す

例えば　
"sample12345_abc_181022.txt"
から、pathlibのstemを使ってパス要素の末尾から拡張子を除いたものを取得して
"sample12345_abc_181022"
から
"sample_abc_181022"を取り出したい＝"12345"を取り除きたい
先頭７番目から11番目を取り除きたい
もしくは、
先頭１番目から６番目と12番目から22番目を取り出して繋げて書き出す。

Comment: 具体的な例 (対象の文字列と抜き出した結果) があると回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: ということは、正規表現の条件の書き方は、対象ファイルよって変わる（より適切な書き方が変わる）ということですね？。できれば、想定されるファイル名全て（英数大文字小文字特殊文字）に対応できる条件が知りたいのですが、それは無理なのですかね？

Comment: @nsguitarns さん、「対象ファイルよって変わる」と言うより、正規表現を使用する場合は「n番目」と言う発想は通常しないのです。正規表現と言うのは一種のルールで文字列の範囲をマッチングしますから、そのルールがはっきりしないと正規表現の形にできません。「"sample_abc_181022"を取り出したい＝"12345"を取り除きたい」と言う場合の「"12345"」と言うのはどう言うルールで決まるものですか? 後ろの`181022`も数字の並びだから単に数字の並びを取り除きたいのではないですよね? また`sample`で始まる文字列しか処理できなくて良いんでしょうか? 「想定されるファイル名全て（英数大文字小文字特殊文字）に対応できる条件」が知りたいとありますが、「想定されるファイル名」がどんなもので、あなたは一体どんな処理をしたいのかもう少しはっきりしてくれないと「条件」とか「正規表現」の形には表せません。言葉で説明するのが難しければ(何番目なんて言い方での説明は要りませんから)「元データと期待される結果」を出来るだけ沢山お示しいただいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 「先頭1番目から6番目と12番目から22番目を取り出して繋げて書き出す」という事であれば、`s = 'sample12345_abc_181022'` とした場合、`s[:6] + s[11:]` とすると良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 固定で「m文字目(からn文字目)」を取り出したいなら正規表現よりも**スライス**を使った方が簡単なんじゃないでしょうか。 / 挙げられた例だと"181022"は恐らく日付だろうということが分かりますが、その他の部分、例えば"sample"は固定の文字なのか、それとも他の文字列で置き換わるのか等で正規表現も変わってきます。この辺りのパターンが数例ないと正規表現も組めないです。

Comment: みなさま、ご回答ありがとうございます。私自身の正規表現に対する理解度不足が、質問の不明瞭さにつながっているとわかりました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のようなコードで概ね質問にある正規表現になると思います。例では、n = 3 m = 6 で文字列の位置は、0から数えるという条件にしています。なお、`str`はわかりやすいように数字にしていますが、英数大文字小文字特殊文字どれでも同じ結果になります。

```
>>> import re
>>> str = '0123456789'
```

1.n番目からm番目の文字列を抜き出す

```
>>> re.match(r'.{3}(.{4})', str).group(1)
'3456'
```

2.n番目からm番目の文字列を削除する

```
>>> re.sub(r'(.{3})(.{4})', r'\g<1>', str)
'012789'
```

3.最初からn番目までを抜き出す

```
>>> re.match(r'.{3}', str).group(0)
'012'
```

4.最後からn番目までを抜き出す

```
>>> re.search(r'.{3}$', str).group(0)
'789'
```

`.`が任意の文字にマッチし、`.{3}`で任意の文字の3文字にマッチします。

今回のケースであれば、以下のようにスライスをするのが簡単ですが、文字の種別が必要になった時には対応が難しくなります。

```
str[n:m+1]
str[:n] + str[m+1]
str[:n]
str[-n:]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。だいぶ理解が深まりました。”文字の種別が必要になった時にはスライスでは対応が難しくなる”というのは、具体的にはどのような事なのでしょうか？大文字、小文字、特殊文字が混在しているような場合ですか？

Comment: 「文字の種別が必要になった時」というのはあまり気にしないでください。質問の「n番目からm番目の文字列を抜き出す」というような単純ケースは、通常スライスを使うので正規表現は使いませんが、できないわけではありません。理解するためにはこういう単純なケースを試してみるのはいいことです。実際には、もう少し複雑な条件での抜き出しが出てくくるので、そういう場合には正規表現を使うことを検討すると簡潔に処理ができるケースが結構あります。

Comment: なるほど、正規表現について少し理解が深まりました。スライスでは処理できない場合（n番目からm番目の文字列を抜き出す」というような単純ケースではない場合）に、適切な正規表現により簡潔に処理できる場合があるのですね。文字の位置ではなく、文字の種類で判別する場合等で、有効だろうと想像できます。ありがとうございました。